# How can I make inferences using the Tensorflow Cifar10 tutorial code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am an absolute beginner to TensorFlow.

If I have a picture (or set of pictures) that I would like to attempt to classify using the code from the Cifar10 TensorFlow tutorial, how would I do so?

I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Train the model using base CIFAR10 dataset exactly as per the tutorial.
2. Create a new graph with your own inputs - probably easiest to just use a `tf.placeholder` and feed the data as per below, but there's lots of other ways.
3. Start a session, load previously saved weights.
4. Run the session (with a `feed_dict` if you're using a `placeholder` as above).

.

```
import tensorflow as tf

train_dir = '/tmp/cifar10_train'  # or use FLAGS as in the train example
batch_size = 8
height = 32
width = 32

image = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, height, width, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)
std_img = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
logits = cifar10.inference(std_img)
predictions = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1)

def get_image_data_batches():
    n_batchs = 100
    for i in range(n_batchs):
        yield (np.random.uniform(size=(batch_size, height, width, 3)*255).astype(np.uint8)

def do_stuff_with(logit_vals, prediction_vals):
    pass

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # restore variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir))
    # run inference
    for batch_data in get_image_data_batches():
        logit_vals, prediction_vals = sess.run([logits, predictions], feed_dict={image: image_data})
        do_stuff_with(logit_vals, prediction_vals)
```

There are better ways of getting data into the graph (see `tf.data.Dataset`), but I believe `tf.placeholder`s are the easiest way for learning and getting something up and running initially.

Also check out `tf.estimator.Estimator`s for a cleaner way of managing sessions. It's very different to the way it's done in this tutorial and -slightly- less flexible, but for standard networks they save you writing a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and mark it as solved if it gets me there. Thank you!